# How to get class of specific parent Element in angular 2 on click anchor tag?

Tags: angular

I am using like this in my HTML file:

```
       <div class="component" >
           <div class="component-header"  >
              <a href="javascript:" (click)="onClick($event)" >
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
              </a>
           </div>
      </div>
```

And in my JS file getting the class as:

```
onClick(event) {
    var target = event.target;
    var pElement = target.parentElement.parentElement;
    var pclassAttr = pElement.attributes.class;
    console.log(pclassAttr);
  }
```

Actually some time it consider that I’m clicking on the anchor and console class is "component" and some times it consider that I’m clicking on the "fa fa-chevron-right" and console class "component-header".

I need always console class as "component" when click on anchor.

Is there any thing wrong please suggest.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use `currentTarget` instead of `target`. It will always be your anchor element because

> **currentTarget** always refers to the element to which the event
>   handler has been attached:

```
onClick(event) {
  var target = event.currentTarget;

  var pElement = target.parentElement.parentElement;
  var pclassAttr = pElement.attributes.class;
  console.log(pclassAttr);
}
```

See also

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget

Comment: It doesn't select to it ( to the element to which the event handler has been attached) in angular 4 when I test to the multiple element which has same class and click handler.

Comment: @klaudia please create reproduction